# How to find the right box to be opened to match the exterior labels if only one extraction is allowed?

Tags: logical-deduction

I found this riddle in a collection of problems from my Reason and Logic's book from 2003. From the looks of it seems to be adapted from Martin Gardner's 70s book.

The problem is as follows:

> Mike has 3 equal carton boxes. In one of them he places candies, then
> in the other one he puts chocolates and finally in the last one he
> places chocolates and candies. Then he proceeds to close them very
> tightly using a tape. However he makes a mistake and uses a wrong
> label to name the contents of each box, so they don't match any of the
> contents. What box does he has to open to label them right if he can
> only take out one item from that box?.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{The one who says "candies"}\\
2.&\textrm{The one who says "chocolates"}\\
3.&\textrm{The one who says "chocolates and candies"}\\
4.&\textrm{Either the one who says "candies" or "chocolates" indistinctly}\\
5.&\textrm{Any of the boxes}\\
\end{array}$

For this particular situation, I don't know how to find the right logic.

At the beginning I felt dumbfounded since to me, one of the choices I found it somewhat confusing and I'm referring to the fourth option. My logic was that if he takes out one piece of the box which says "candies" and he finds chocolates. This will make the other two boxes to be either candies or chocolate and candies.

This will make that the box which has the name "chocolate" to be filled with "candies". But this will cause the box which has "chocolates and candies" to be correctly named, hence it will be contrary to what the problem is telling as it indicates **"all labels are put wrong"**. In other words and **absurd**.

Hence I concluded that the only way that it can match with what is intended to mean with the boxes assigned incorrectly would be:

- **"chocolates" = has candies or has candies and chocolates**
- **"candies" = has chocolates or candies and chocolates**
- **"chocolate and candies"= has "chocolates" or "candies"**

Therefore I believe this would be the logic to take out one item from the box which says **"chocolate and candies"** first.

But is this the right way to approach this problem?. Does it exist some sort of diagram or whatsoever?. Can someone help me with this?.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe target: with three boxes labeled ABC which are all wrong, the only two possible states are BCA and CAB. Therefore if you pick one item from "chocolates and candies", you can immediately deduce all boxes' contents.

Comment: @Bubbler I'm sorry I don't get what you meant with TL and DR. What's the meaning of these?. Did you meant *too long didn't read*?. Why did you used it?. My question was aimed to know if my logical deduction was right?. But more properly why?.

Comment: You can see your question is linked to a different question with the same solution, right? I meant to give you a summary of the solution. Or you can just go to that question and read the full logic in the answer.